# UPDATE a tabla mysql con json y ajax (jquery)

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, mysqli

estoy creando un CRUD del cual obtengo los datos desde una tabla mysql que luego convierto a json.
El punto es que logro listar los datos en mi HTML, pero lo que no se hacer es actualizar los campos al momento de presionar editar desde mi modal(bootstrap).

En concreto no se como tendria que ir mi archivo editar.php para que realice la actualización de los datos en la tabla mysql y luego sean reflejados en la tabla en la vista HTML.

Les dejo el codigo que tengo hasta al momento :

// Codigo php de editar.php

```
<?php
include_once('conexion.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM productos";
$resource = $conn->query($query);
$total = $resource->num_rows;

while ($row = $resource->fetch_assoc()){
//print_r($row);
    $row['nombre']=utf8_encode($row['nombre']);
    $row['categoria']=utf8_encode($row['categoria']);
    $row['frase_promocional']=utf8_encode($row['nombre']);
    $row['descripcion']=utf8_encode($row['descripcion']);

  $array[] = $row;
 
}

///listando json///

 if(json_encode($array))
 {echo json_encode($array);} 
 else{ echo json_last_error_msg();}
/* echo "<pre>",print_r($array, 1),"</pre>"; */


/// EDITAR /// 


if(isset($_GET['editar'])){
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id=$id") or die($mysqli->error());
}
```

Codigo Jquery de editar.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Abre el Modal
    $('#modalEditar').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
        var identificador = button.data('identificador')
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-body #identificador').val(identificador)
        
       /*  var imagen = button.data('imagen'); */
        var nombre = button.data('nombre')
        var descripcion = button.data('descripcion')
        var codigo = button.data('codigo')
        var categoria = button.data('categoria')
        var frase_promocional = button.data('frase_promocional')
        var colores = button.data('colores')
        var precio = button.data('precio')
        var disponibilidad = button.data('disponibilidad')
        var promocion = button.data('promocion')
        var fecha = button.data('fecha')

        /* modal.find('.modal-body #url-imagen').val(imagen); */
        modal.find('.modal-body #nombre').val(nombre)
        modal.find('.modal-body #descripcion').val(descripcion)
        modal.find('.modal-body #codigo').val(codigo)
        modal.find('.modal-body #categoria').val(categoria)
        modal.find('.modal-body #frase_promocional').val(frase_promocional)
        modal.find('.modal-body #colores').val(colores)
        modal.find('.modal-body #precio').val(precio)
        modal.find('.modal-body #disponibilidad').val(disponibilidad)
        modal.find('.modal-body #promocion').val(promocion)
        modal.find('.modal-body #fecha').val(fecha)
       
      })

    // Editando la base de datos correspondiente
    $('#editar_btn').click(function() {
        console.log("Editando")

        /* var imagen = $('#modalEditar #url-imagen').val(); */
        var nombre = $('#modalEditar #nombre').val()
        var descripcion = $('#modalEditar #descripcion').val()
        var identificador = $('#modalEditar #identificador').val()

        var codigo = $('#modalEditar #codigo').val()
        var categoria = $('#modalEditar #categoria').val()
        var frase_promocional = $('#modalEditar #frase_promocional').val()
        var colores = $('#modalEditar #colores').val()
        var precio = $('#modalEditar #precio').val()
        var promocion = $('#modalEditar #promocion').val()
        var fecha = $('#modalEditar #fecha').val()

        var json = {
            "columnas": ["nombre", "descripcion","codigo","categoria","frase_promocional","colores","precio", "disponibilidad","promocion","fecha"],
            "valores": [nombre,descripcion,codigo,categoria,frase_promocional,colores,precio,disponibilidad,promocion,fecha ],
            "indice": "id",
            "valor_indice": identificador,
            "tabla": "productos",
        }

        // metodo post
        $.post({
            url: 'editar.php', //editar
            data: {'editar': json},
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(respuesta) {
                if (respuesta == 1) {
                    listar_productos();
                    $('#modalEditar').modal('hide')
                } else {
                    console.error("Problemas al editar producto")
                    console.error(respuesta)
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                console.error("Sin Respuesta editar producto");
            }
        });

        

    });
    
});
```

Comment: La petición AJAX que estás enviando es de tipo POST por el `$.post()` y en PHP lo estás intentando recuperar como un GET por el `$_GET[]`. Cambia el PHP a `$_POST[]`.

Comment: este mensaje de error me da : Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: ¿En qué línea te da ese error? ¿Es de PHP o de JS?